# How to get total number of lines in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know how to do this? Preferably xml and java together, but java alone also works. I need this specifically for Android Studio, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out the [Statistic](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4509) plugin for Android Studio/IntelliJ - it will give you the info you need :)

[image: All File Types]

[image: Java Files]

Note: even though you can't see it in the screenshot, it does also list line counts for xml files.

Comment: My pleasure. I was just as happy when I discovered this little gem :)

Comment: @free3dom Sexy thankyou very much. Used to show off by showing complete lines of code to friends and family.

Comment: I managed to install it but I don't know how can I run the plugin :) I'm stuck in Android Studio.

Comment: @Ehsan You can run this plugin from menu View -> Tools Windows -> Statistic

Comment: How to exclude generated files from libraries like Dagger and Parceler?

Comment: Crashes on Android studio 1.5.1